# how to use offline map tiles data

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, dictionary, tiles

I want to write offline map tile data.
By the way, I do not know what to do.

I found such an answer, but I do not know how to do it.
Do I need to create map tiles directly?

And to respond to the low order received open map street data
I used Josm, osmosis, but I do not know how.

I finally use it with 3d and make MBtiles file.

Comment: You don't need to create map tiles, map data are available from `openstreetmaps` there are frameworks available some paid, some free, you can choose any they do all the processing of data from openstreetmaps, try [omim](https://github.com/mapsme/omim) or [skobbler](http://www.skobbler.com/)

Comment: Are you using Apache Tiles for this app? If no, you should consider removing the tag, which specifically says it's for that framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by using the [route-me library](https://github.com/route-me/route-me) and following [this](http://shiki.me/blog/offline-maps-in-ios-using-openstreetmap-and-route-me/) tutorial for tile download

Note that you may have to tweek the library for newer iOS versions.